# Windows 8 Problem installing Ubuntu - Bios Setting

Tags: dual-boot

I have managed to install ubuntu 13.04 on my Samsung 370R, it said it was successful. But whenever I try to boot it, it does not allow.

I have attached couple of printscreen photos of my bios. Can you please advise what should be the right settings?

Comment: where are attachments? update bios to latest version

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the attachments but you should make sure that you've disabled

> Secure Boot

from boot options